# XML parsing with dom and special characters

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, special-characters

I'm attempting to parse xml containing foreign letters (æøå specifically), however I'm having problems making parsing them successfully. I don't get any errors, but the letters are parsed as this; Instead of æ im getting Ã¦, instead of å im getting Ã¥ and instead of ø im getting Ã¸
I also just noticed the char - isn't displaying properly.
I realise I could do .replaceAll for the 3 letters, but I'm not sure if the problem here its down to me making a mistake somewhere or if its just not possible without going down the route of replaceAll.

The code:

```
    private Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    xml.getBytes()));
            // is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            Log.i(TAG, "Encoding: " + is.getEncoding());
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        // return DOM
        return doc;
    }

    private String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

    private final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                        .getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need to see more code than this.

Appreciate any suggestions - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are converting the String argument to bytes using `getBytes()`. You'd be better off not converting to bytes at all:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
```

I see that you have that commented out in the code. Is there any reason you don't want to use it?

If you *have* to use a byte array, it's best to do it like this:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
    xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

On older versions of Android, the default charset depended on the locale.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Following your suggestions I've tried the following:
    InputSource is = new InputeSource(new ByteArrayInpuStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"))); and

InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

None of these approaches made any difference. The is.setCharacterStream is a left over of attempts to solve this issue, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @Line - Perhaps the encoding was messed up when the xml String was first created (before the call to `getDomElement`). Perhaps check that the input string actually has the characters you expect.

Comment: An example of the xml I try to parse is here: 
    HttpResponse loginResponse = loginClient.execute(loginPost);
    HttpEntity responseEnt = loginResponse.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(responseEnt); //This is the string thats given to the parser. Could the EnitityUtils.toString() cause problems?

I am, however, able to use the xml that I parse to check for different information parsed back to the phone from the website API.

Comment: @Line - Bingo! Try using `String result = EntityUtils.toString(responseEnt, "UTF-8");`. If the response itself does not specify a charset, then the default behavior of EntityUtils is to use `HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET`, which is ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is assuming that the platforms default encoding is "UTF-8"; I think in fact it might be "UTF-16".

Try passing the same encoding name to xml.getBytes() as you do to is.setEncoding().

Comment: According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html): _"On Android, the default charset is UTF-8."_ (On older versions of Android, the default depended on the locale, but I don't believe it is ever UTF-16.)